# Attempting to Join Multiple MYSQL tables in one statement using Foreign Keys

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to execute a MYSQL statement which will allow a user to view all details of a 'proposal' in one table. However there are about 5 different tables I need to connect and the there are two conditions:

Condition 1: source must equal 'Supervisor'
Condition 2: a record in the table 'record' must not exist.

This is my attempt so far for some of the tables which keeps getting an error in the sql query builder in phpMyAdmin:

```
SELECT p.proposal_id, p.proposal_title, p.description, t.tag_code, c.course_title, u.forename, u.surname, FROM proposal p
LEFT JOIN proposal_tags t USING (proposal_id)
            LEFT JOIN course_details c USING (course_code)
            LEFT JOIN user u USING (user_record_id);
```

The Table Structure is as follows:

`**proposal**` (`proposal_id`, `source`, `proposal_title`, `description`, `date_added`, `course_code`, `user_record_id`)

`**proposal_tags**` (`proposal_id`, `tag_code`)

`**tag_details**` (`tag_code`, `tag_title`)

`**user_details**` (`user_record_id`, `forename`, `surname`)

`**course_details**` (`course_code`, `course_title`)

I would like the table to look like this:

[image: Table for Proposal]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance guys!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the `tag_details` table as well with the `proposal_tags` and for `Supervisor Name` you can use `concat` function something as

```
SELECT 
p.proposal_id as `Proposal Id`, 
p.proposal_title as `Proposal Title`, 
p.description as Description, 
concat(u.forename,' ', u.surname) as `Supervisor Name`,
c.course_title as Course,
t.tag_title as Tags,
p.date_added as `Date Added`
FROM proposal p
LEFT JOIN proposal_tags pt on pt.proposal_id =  p.proposal_id
LEFT JOIN tag_details t on t.tag_code = pt.tag_code
LEFT JOIN course_details c on c.course_code = p.course_code
LEFT JOIN user u on u.user_record_id = p.user_record_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Abhik. Would this return the tag_code as tag_code and then course_code as course_title? I ask this because I want the names of the codes to be displayed instead of the number

Comment: No it will not display the tag code just the `tag_title` from `tag_details`

Comment: Brilliant I'll give it a go! Thanks once again :)